# Debug on condition Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, random, logic

I have written a code for a random KnowledgeBase generator in Java, which generates a set of implications and facts as well in order to prove them.
Unluckly between the generated facts there are facts which aren't included in any generated implication (for ex. generated implications: a=>b;c=>d; generated facts: a,e).
This bug doesn't occur every time I run my program, but only few times.
My question is if, in Eclipse, there's a way to run the debug when this condition happens, and how I can localize the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a piece of your code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint where you want to check the condition.

Right click on the breakpoint and click on "Breakpoint Properties"

Select Conditional and add the appropriate condition possibilities and the debugger breaks when these are true.

Comment: But si there a way to go back band find the bug? I mean, in the way you wrote the debug will be launched when the problem  already occured... I need it to go back and reso the previouses programma steps in order to find the error

Comment: @user3125168 how could you walk back in the execution of a program?? no there is no way to go back in debug mode, you will need to put the breakpoint somewhere before the erroneous generation happens and then walk step by step, maybe multiple times..

Comment: You put a condition as: !(a>=b || c>=d) , which are non required implications and u cannot back the execution of already executed statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a conditional debug point in eclipse and specify you condition.

Have a look at below links to know how to apply contitional breakpoints

- http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-manage_conditional_breakpoint.htm
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F